# MagicalRecord crashed on ios8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, magicalrecord

+[CDSession findFirstWithPredicate:inContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x919b3c

What has changed in ios 8? It worked well with ios7. I can't get it approveed.

**UPD**

After rename methods with prefix i catch next error:

```
results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
Terminating app due to     uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.
```

**UPD1**

Early happy. on simulator MR work fine without prefix, but on devices crash with :

```
"createEntity]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x8eafec"
```

add prefix pass this place, but crash on

```
return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[self MR_entityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];`
```

with error:

```
"CDSession" is not a subclass of NSManagedObject.
```

i think its a bug of iOs8

**UPD2**

i created simple project http://cl.ly/2b0R2I3W3Y1P it crashed on devices with iOS8 but working fine on simulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On devices was added CoreDuet framework with some class name like `CDSession`. i just rename this class and all working correctly now.

Comment: "Just" rename? How in earth did you figure this out?

Comment: @JosipB. skill other iOS developers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the MR_ prefix on all your methods.

Comment: thx for advice, but it call other error: on line `results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'` o_O